# Why does data.table notation for column selection affect speed

Tags: r, data.table

There seem to be a difference in speed depending in how you specify the columns to be selected from a data.table: `x[, .(var)]` vs `x[, c('var')]`.
The reason may be completely obvious, however in the help page `.()`, `list()` and `c()` notations seem to be used interchangeably. 
I work with quite large datasets, so it is a bit important to me :-)

Example (the order of call does not affect the speed):

```
x <- as.data.table(as.character(rnorm(20000000,1,0.5)))
setkey(x, V1)

tic(); x[, .(V1)]; toc()
25.08 sec elapsed


tic(); x[, c('V1')]; toc()
0.28 sec elapsed

tic(); x[, 1]; toc()
0.02 sec elapsed

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tictoc_1.0        data.table_1.12.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1  tools_3.6.1     lifecycle_0.2.0 rlang_0.4.6
```

Comment: if you want to extract a single column, you can use either `x[["V1"]]` or `x$V1`

Comment: yet these would return a vector while the mentioned ways return a single column data.table

Comment: there are overheads with creating data.table and some of the package contributors/authors are trying to reduce the overhead. Why does the user want to create a single column data.table? i.e. what is he going to do next with the single column data.table? Why is there a need to copy the column all over again?

Comment: Thx for reading! @chinsoon12: it is not a question of how to extract the columns - or why. It is a question of why there is a large performance differences between notations (where the notation stated  in the cheat sheat, is extremely slow with tlarge datasets). Hope it makes sense..

Comment: @user9439449 you might want to read through the slides, posts, articles, and comments by Matt Dowle at the beginning. It was designed in a certain way to eliminate some of the unnecessary stuff to make it fast.

Comment: Hi @user9439449 thanks for your question, it's now a bug report here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4498 Please add your name there if you'd like to be cited besides as `user9439449` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have found a bug (issue filed [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4498))-- `data.table` is trying to determine if the output of `[]` is keyed; in order to do so, it is running an internal `is.sorted` function. This is very slow on a huge table of unique strings.

Fortunately, we can do static analysis and realize that your output table is in fact keyed -- there's no subset, and the key column (`V1`) is unchanged. Therefore the sort order cannot have changed, and your output will also be sorted by `V1`.

This logic is built in to a [PR to fix this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4498) -- you can test it out with `remotes::install_github('Rdatatable/data.table@fix_sorting_on_sorted')`, with the caveat that this is a bleeding edge version of the package, or you can wait till it's merged to master, or until a new version is released to CRAN.

In the meantime, here's a workaround:

```
setkey(x, NULL)
system.time(x[ , .(V1)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.120   0.087   0.213
```

Of course this blocks later processing from recognizing that your data is sorted & the efficiencies thereto...

In this case (!and this case only -- use with care!!!) -- where you are yourself certain that the data is already sorted by `V1` -- you can restore the key instantly with:

```
setattr(x, 'sorted', 'V1')
```

---

More generally there are small differences among selection with `[`, `[[`, `$`, etc. `[` will tend to be the slowest since we do a lot of "static query analysis" to help improve the efficiency of your code, which comes with a performance cost which *we hope* will be small almost every time. Anytime this cost is not small, it should be a bug. There is also some work being done actively to try and offer shortcuts to reduce this overhead, see for example [this PR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4488)

Comment: Thanx for all your work on this (and other issues) - it is highly appreciated!